# ODS Tagsets RTF

Tags: sas, sas-ods, proc-report

I am trying to make underscores (_) appear in my output while using ODS Tagsets but for some unknown reasons it's not appearing as expected. I'm using SAS 9.4.
It appears with Bodytitle and Bodytitle_aux but the pagebreaking is much better with Tagsets.

Unfortunately using unicode doesn't work either. 
Here is a sample code:

> ```
> options nonumber; 
> %let path=;
> ods path(prepend) work.templat(update);
> proc template ;
> define style newstyle ;
>   parent = styles.journal ;
>   class Parskip /
>       font = fonts("headingFont")
>       cellpadding = 0 cellspacing = 0  /* Only for Measured */
>       frame= void
>       Rules = NONE
>       BorderWidth = 0
>       Color = _undef_
>       BackGroundColor = _undef_;
>   style byline                          / font_face="Courier New"  font_style=Roman background = white;
>   style Body from Document              / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman background = white;
>  style data                            / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  ;
>   style table                           / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman 
>                                       bordercolor=black background = white borderwidth=1 ;
>  style cellcontents                    / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  ;
>   style TitleAndNoteContainer           / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  background = white;
>   style ProcTitle                       / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  ;
>   style systemtitle                      / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  ;
>   style rowheader from headersandfooters / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  ;
>   style BodyDate                         / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  ;
>   style PageNo                           / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman ;
>   style SysTitleAndFooterContainer       / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman ;
>   style header from headersandfooters    / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman  background = white;
>   style SystemFooter                     / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman bordercolor=black background = white borderwidth=1 ;
>   style NoteContent                      / font_face="Courier New" font_style=Roman font_size=8pt;
> end;
> run ;
>
>
> options papersize=letter leftmargin=3.65cm rightmargin=2.11cm topmargin=3.36cm bottommargin=3.3cm orientation=landscape;
> ods escapechar="^"; 
> ods tagsets.rtf file="&path.\shoes2file.rtf" options(vspace='no') options(continue_tag="no"); 
>  ods tagsets.rtf style=newstyle ;
>  title1 'Title: Shoes';
> proc report data=sashelp.shoes(obs=10) nowd style(header)=[rules=group frame=above background=white font_size=8pt] 
>         style(report)=[outputwidth=100% rules=group frame=hsides background=white font_size=8pt ]  
>         style(column)=[rules=group font_size=8pt] spanrows; 
>   column region product; 
>   define region / '___Region___' display style(column)=[width=1.5cm asis=on just=l] style(hdr)=[asis=on just=l]; 
>   define product / '___Product___' display style(column)=[width=1.5cm asis=on just=l] style(hdr)=[asis=on just=l]; 
>  footnote 'Footnote Page L____4';   
> run; 
>
> ods tagsets.rtf close;
>    options nonumber
>            nocenter nobyline nodate formdlim='' 
>            formchar="|_---|+|---+=|-/\<>*" MISSING=" " ;
> ```

In the attached photo, the highlighted circles are the places where underscores are supposed to be. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Are the underscores in the RTF file?  If so then the issue must lie with how WORD (or whatever tool) is rendering the file . Look that the file as a simple text file to check.

Comment: True, it appears when viewed in notepad++. In fact if I keep zooming and un-zooming in Word sometimes it appears and other times it disappears. However, this doesn't happen with bodytitle, it's always present. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in Courier font (really Courier New) the underscore is below even the tail of the normal characters (which makes it really useful for underlining by "overstriking").

I am not sure how to fix the style to do it but I was able to get it to show the underscores by changing the spacing after the "paragraphs" from 0 point to 1 points.  Here is data step that replaces all `\sa0` commands in your RTF file with `\sa20`.  The resulting file shows the underscores.

```
data _null_;
  infile "&path/shoes2file.rtf";
  file "&path/shoes2file_fixed.rtf";
  input;
  _infile_ = tranwrd(_infile_,'\sa0','\sa20');
  put _infile_;
run;
```